# Waiting in Unity 3D game engine in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait

Is there a command in Unity 3D game engine with C# to make the code wait before something happens? Here is an example:

```
void Start () {
    //(wait code here)
    Connect();
}
```

Comment: Void Start() is a set Unity Game Engine code piece, can you clarify that you ARE or ARE NOT using the Unity Game Engine, as the tag Unity in Stack overflow is **NOT** for the Game Engine ?

Comment: Please read the [tag:unity] description before using it next time :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The promoted way of doing this with the Unity3D Game Engine tutorials is with `WaitForSeconds` which waits for a given float value (such as 0.5f for half a second).

But with this rule you need to set the class to an `IEnumerator` so:

```
public flat StartWait;

IEnumerator SpawnWaves ()
    {
        //your code
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (StartWait);
    }
```

This causes the class/object to wait without freezing the whole game logic. See also 
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/spawning-waves

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html

Answer (score 0):

Use start function like that to wait for certain seconds

```
using System.Collections;  //using this libarary mandatory
private IEnumerator Start()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
            //Then do this
        }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35000155)